# About the global keyword in python

Tags: python

```
# coding: utf-8

def func():
    print 'x is', x
    #x = 2   #if I add this line, there will be an error, why?
    print 'Changed local x to', x
x = 50
func()
print 'Value of x is', x
```

1. I don't add the `global x` in func function, but it can still find `x` is 50, why?
2. When I add the `x=2` line in the func function, there will be an error (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`), why?

Comment: @Marcin if I add the x = 2, the error is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Then put that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is that **local names are detected statically**:

- As long as the name `x` is not assigned in the function, references to `x` resolve to the the global scope
- If the name `x` is assigned **anywhere** in the function, Python assumes that `x` is thus a local name **everywhere** in the function. As a consequence, the first line becomes an error because local name `x` is used before being assigned.

In other words: assigned name is treated as local everywhere in the function, not just after the point of assignment.

Answer (score 4):

The `global` keyword is required only to write to globals.

There is an error because assigning to a variable which is not declared global creates a local variable of that name. You refer to `x` in that scope before it is assigned to, so you are attempting to read a local variable which has not yet been assigned.

Answer (score 3):

Python uses fairly typical [variable scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). Non-local variables are visible within a function.

You only need `global` keyword if you want to assign to a variable within global scope.
Also you have to note the difference between global and outer scope. Consider implications:

```
x = 'global'
def f():
    x = 'local in f'
    def g():
        global x 
        x = 'assigned in g'
    g()
    print x
```

Upon execution of `f()` above code will print `local in f`, while `x` in global scope is set to `'assigned in g'`.

---

As of Python 3, there is also `nonlocal` keyword, which allows you assigning to variable from outer scope.

```
x = 'global'
def f():
    x = 'local in f'
    def g():
        nonlocal x 
        x = 'assigned in g'
    return g
    print(x)
```

Upon execution of `f()` above code will print 'assigned in g`(which is the value of`x`in local scope of`f()`), while value of`x` in global scope remains untouched.

It's also worth to note, that Python uses lexical (static) scoping, thus following code does **not** modify the `x` in the global scope:

```
x = 'global'
def f():
    x = 'local in f'
    def g():
        nonlocal x 
        x = 'assigned in g'
    return g
g = f()
g()
```

Comment: If you want to discuss the technical merits of something, do it constructively and maturely. Don't get into kiddish name-calling and fighting. Thanks.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't see the disrespect you mention on this answer. oh..wait (checks English dictionary for `typical` ) ah .. tehre it is - it looks like this word has a negative cognation in English it does not get in other languages -  Vartec, being a non-native speaker probably was not aware of that. """ 1. being or serving as a representative example of a particular type; characteristic the painting is a typical Rembrandt
2. considered to be an example of some undesirable trait that is typical of you!"""}(collins dict) - around the World, the first meaning is more spread)

Comment: @jsbueno: Well, it wasn't really an issue with the answer... it was something else.